# Check for duplicate before adding into array, using pointers

Tags: c++

I have a global static Strings str[MAX] = { "aloha" , "behold", "donkey", "key", "joke", "none", "quack", "orange"};

The size here was randomly generated, for example if size = 3, it will print out "Behold", "donkey" and "none". Before adding into the array, i want to check if it is inside.
if "Behold", "donkey", "none" is inside the array, and if i get another word, "donkey", it will reject and go back to loop and generate another one, thus i use i--

I'm not sure where went wrong, i hope someone can enlighten me.

Thanks. Here's the code.

```
typedef char* Strings;

function example (Strings *s, int size)
{
    char *q;

    bool check;

    q = new char[MAX];

    *s = &q[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        k = rand () % 8;
        if (*s == '\0')
            *s = Str[k];
        else
        {
            check = compare (s, Str[k]);

            if (check == 1)
                *s = Str[k];
            else
                i--;
        }
        ++s;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

bool compare (Strings *s, char *str)
{
    while (*s != '\0')
    {
        if (strcmp (*s, Str))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
        ++s;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)? Then you can just add string and still be sure there's only unique strings in the collection.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg looks like the assignment is to use pointers. Throwing duplicates of all the data into a `std::set<std::string>`, while obviously a solution, is likely out of the realm of allowances. (the "using pointers" in the question title was my hint, at least).

Comment: Using `char*` for strings is not a good idea, hiding it behind a `typedef` makes it worse...

Comment: I'm positively *dying* to know the logic behind the `rand() % 8` index check and followup assignment, almost as much as my curiosity of what `Str` is and where it comes from (or was this code *not* supposed to even compile)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `std::set` stores data in a sorted order, if memory serves me well. The task seems to require a group of strings that are shuffled. BTW, does `std::unordered_set` guarantee to preserve the order of elements in which they were added?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using pointers and arrays...

First, write `char ** find( const char * what, const char ** begin, const char ** end )` function that would search range from `begin` to `end` until it meets an element equal to `what` or until it reaches `end`. Equality of elements can be determined by `strcmp` function.

Second, use it. After you picked a `random_string`, try `find` it within your `output_array`.

Like that:

```
const size_t Str_count = 8;
const char * Str[ Str_count ] =
{
    "aloha",
    "behold",
    "donkey",
    "key",
    "joke",
    "none",
    "quack",
    "orange"
};

const char **
find( const char * what, const char ** begin, const char ** end )
{
    while( begin != end )
    {
        if( !strcmp( what, *begin ) )
            break;

        begin++;
    }

    return begin;
}

int
generate( char ** output_array, size_t size )
{
    if( size > Str_count )
    {
        // infinite loop would occur
        return 1;
    }

    size_t i = 0;

    while( i < size )
    {
        const char * random_string = Str[ rand() % Str_count ]; // random index in [0-7] I suppose...

        // if we did not encounter the same string within the output_array
        if(    &output_array[ size ]
            == find
               (
                   random_string,
                   ( const char ** ) output_array,
                   ( const char ** ) &output_array[ size ]
               )
          )
        {
            // put the string in there
            output_array[ i ] = new char[ strlen( random_string ) ];
            strcpy( output_array[ i ], random_string );

            ++i;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This works, but I should warn you: having global variables like that is generally considered to be 'bad programming style'. Additionally, this is not really the C++ way, as it is pure C code.